# problem with solving Compound interest?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

An amount is invested at $33.33\%$ compounded annually.
What is the ratio of Compound interest for $4$ and $3$ years?
My approach: The fractional increment in each year is $\frac{4}{3}$.
For 4 years the fraction will be $\frac{256}{81}$ and the difference between the numerator and denominator will be the compound interest i.e 175.
Similarly for 3 years the fraction will be $\frac{64}{27}$ and the difference will be 37.
Hence the Ratio of Compound interest for 4 and 3 years will be $175:37$.
However, the answer is $175:111$, but I can't figure out how this method is giving wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the denominator the same for the two settings:

$$256 - 81 = 175$$

$$64(3)-27(3)=37(3)=111$$

Comment: Can you please explain why >

Comment: $81$ is the initial amount that you put in initially. In $3$ years it grows to $64(3)$, in constrast with $4$ years it grows to $256$.